# Which song plays during Bleach episode 45 around 10:00

Tags: music, bleach

Bleach "Episode 45" S3 E4 time: 10:00 On *Netflix*
During Bleach EP45 S3 E4 at 10:00 on Netflix there plays a song. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

The song played is [Requiem For The Lost Ones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JW8QbLjZbF8), from the first OST of Bleach.